# SQL serverにて、複数のテーブルを縦方向に連結させたい

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQLのテーブルについての質問です。
【やりたいこと】
SQL server上で、多数のテーブル（カラム等は同じ）を、全て縦につなげたい
（UNIONを使ってもいいが、たとえばテーブルが100件あると一つ一つ書くのが面倒に）

【詳細】
現在、日々のログデータ(Excel, 100000行/day)を
[20171015]、[20171016]、[20171017]…という名前でExcelシートに保存しており、
それらのシートを一括でSQL serverにインポートしています。

この方法だと、SQL server上ではテーブルがシートの数だけ（つまり日数分）
作成されています。

ここから月毎、年単位での分析をするときに、
一度に読み込めるようそれらのシートをすべて縦に繋げたいのですが

UNION句を使う方法では、シートの数だけUNIONが必要になってしまい、
非常に書くのが難しく(面倒くさく)なってしまい、見栄えもよくありません。

良い方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

登録時にテーブルに分割しているのが問題の根本のように感じます。ExcelをCSVなどにエクスポートして一つのテーブルにインポートしてはどうでしょうか。マクロなどを使えば、うまく自動化できると思いますし、毎月クエリを書き換えなくても済みます。

Answer (score 0):

> UNION句を使う方法では、シートの数だけUNIONが必要になってしまい、
>   非常に書くのが難しく(面倒くさく)なってしまい、見栄えもよくありません。

SQL文を直接書くのでなく、マクロなどで生成すればいいのでは？

なお一般的には[パーティション テーブル](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes)を使用して１つのテーブルのまま分割します。